# Grails - associations by referencing id only

Tags: grails, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to employ Domain Driven Design into my application, and in order to limit deep traversal between aggregate roots, the advice is to associate them using only their identities. Say I have the following domain classes,

Person

```
class Person {

  Integer age

  String name

}
```

and PhoneBill

```
class PhoneBill {

  // reference to Person
  Long accountHolderId

  BigDecimal amount

}
```

As it is, this setup can already work. However, I want to add foreign key constraint to `accountHolderId` just to make sure any value set to it already exists in the data store. The official Grails docs don't seem to cover this.

Comment: Use database migrations and manage your foreign key constrains from there. Since you aren't modeling your relationship using GORM/Grails domain classes it's up to you now.

Comment: This is what I was originally planning, I just didn't know (actually forgot about) database migrations. The downside with this, I think, is that it makes it a little difficult to change data store, especially to NoSQL types. Is that right?

Comment: Why would you use NoSQL datastore for relational data? That's best put into a RDBMS. I'm not sure if the database migration plugin works with non RDBMS.

Comment: There are many reasons to use NoSQL as alternative to SQL databases, even for data like these.

Comment: Fair enough, my comment was just simply to make sure you had examined all the options and had based your choice on reason and not just hype. I'm fully aware that there are plenty of good use cases for NoSQL databases, but all too often people just use them without really having a good reason. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Person` object still has an id, you can add a [custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Constraints/validator.html) which returns an error if the `id` isn't valid.

```
class PhoneBill {

  // reference to Person
  Long accountHolderId

  BigDecimal amount

    static constraints = {
        accountHolderId validator: { 
            !Person.exists(it) ?: 'your.custom.error.message.key'
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `.exists()` is only available for Grails 2.3.x, I believe.  If you're using an older version, you can call `.get()` just as well.

Comment: This seems like a better option than migrations approach: 1) it looks easy to test (assertion in DDD); 2) the constraint is expressed in the domain class; 3) introduces no issue when changing data store.

Comment: Good solution if you can ensure that only your domain is used to access the data and someone doesn't access the data directly from the data store, external system/process.

Comment: Well, yes, you have a point there. I guess there's little reason I can't use this with the migrations approach.